# Can't boot operating system

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have a 1TB hard drive containing Windows 7 Home Premium and another 0.7TB hard drive containing Ubuntu Studio. After I installed Ubuntu, I got the new GRUB boot screen, and I wanted to remove it and get the Windows 7 boot screen. Silly as I am, I managed to mess up the boot part, so when I try to boot into Ubuntu I get a message that says: `No operating system found` and when I try to boot Windows I just simply get a black screen with a blinking underscore character. I have a Windows 7 System Repair Disc, but when I tried various commands they resulted in these error messages. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows bootloader cannot boot Ubuntu and Windows. Grub however can, so stick with Grub. Try fixing Grub with the Super Grub Disk found [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/%E2%80%8E)

Comment: yeah i used the supergrub disk but it didnt work, im trying to boot into zorin to try a grub repair tool

Comment: You could always boot the Ubuntu Install disc and manually reinstall grub from the command line too.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 boot can be fixed using Windows 7 Recovery CD/DVD:

1. bootsect /nt60 all /force /mbr
2. bcdboot c:\windows  - where c: is Windows drive, if not change drive letter.

To chain load Ubuntu from Windows boot manager you could use the method described in 
[Dual boot Windows 7 and Linux/UNIX](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html).